# Make a mark on google maps to move in realtime

Tags: google-maps

I have a marker on Google maps and i want it to move in real time (every 10 seconds for example ) towards a point until it goes there.

Is that possible assuming that i got the long and latt of the ending point and the long and latt of the current marker point...

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to simply interpolate latLng positions along the line between the two points, and put all these locations in an array.  Then using using setTimeout or setInterval you can set the location of the marker to the next position in the array.

Without knowing more details it's hard to suggest something more specific, but if you need it to travel along only roads, for example, you could use driving directions and then have it follow the resulting polyline.

Comment: The array approach was my first idea too as i need to give the marker the chance to turn in different diferent direction on corners in a give circle root. But i ask to see if there is another approach like Randow Walk or something...thnx for the reply though